# Using NGrok with POW

Tags: http, ngrok, http-tunneling

I've almost got NGrok working with POW, but it is resolving to the POW without drilling down to the application running on POW.

I can access my local application running on POW at:

```
myapp.dev
```

However when I initialize Ngrok:

```
/Applications/ngrok -subdomain=myapp myapp.dev:80
```

As outlined [here](http://journal.wearebunker.com/post/59684890589/using-ngrok-with-pow-for-development-previews), I receive the following output from NGrok:

```
Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       1.6/1.5
Forwarding                    http://myapp.ngrok.com -> 127.0.0.1:80
Forwarding                    https://myapp.ngrok.com -> 127.0.0.1:80
Web Interface                 127.0.0.1:4040
# Conn                        0
Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

Loading `http://myapp.ngrok.com`resolves to POW, but I get the generic message:

```
Pow is installed
You’re running version 0.4.1
```

**How can I setup NGrok to resolve to my .dev domain?**

Comment: Is the following line in your ~/.powconfig?  
`export POW_EXT_DOMAINS=ngrok.com`  
Some people have had to reinstall pow after adding that line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Might be a bit late to the party, but here it goes.

It seems like you need to modify your Host header.

For example:

```
ngrok http -host-header=myapp.dev mayapp.dev:80
```

This answer only works with ngrok v2.

More info can be found at https://ngrok.com/docs#http

Comment: You're so late that I can't remember what ngrok is or does ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Powder gem and doing "powder restart", which only works for the local site. You might need to restart pow as described in the manual: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_3.3